# Memory usage with winform app

Tags: c#, memory

I have a form that can be dynamically added to a devexpress tab control. When you click the tab for the first time the control is there. You can add additional ones as you see fit. Each one has a delete button on it. However, if you click the add button it adds about 30 MBs under the running process. When you delete one on there the MBs stay in memory.

My delete code:

```
MyCustom temp = this._UIList[idx] as MyCustom;
if (this._UIList.Count == 1)
{
temp.Clear();
}
else
{
if (temp != null)
    {
        this._UIList.RemoveAt(idx);
            this._UIList.TrimToSize();
            this.pnlInner.Controls.Remove(temp);
            temp.CleanUP();
            temp.Dispose();
            //now reshuffle all the note controls
            ReshuffleMyCustomControls();
    }
}
```

Any direction would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: what is `MyCustom`? what does `ReshuffleMyCustomControls` do?

Comment: You should _Temporarily_ add a GC.Collect(); call to be sure the memory just hasn't been garbage collected yet...

Comment: MyCustom is the user control that gets added to the form when the add button is clicked. Reshuffle sets the idx of the one not deleted to 0 and moves it to the top of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you remove any event handlers that got wired up. They can hold the reference in memory.

You'd have to do something like this for any event you wired up:

```
    stripevents(AddressOf Any_Control_ValChanged)
    stripevents(AddressOf Any_EnterControl)
    stripevents(AddressOf Any_LeaveControl)
    stripevents(AddressOf ButtonClick)

Sub stripevents(ByVal eh As EventHandler)
    [Delegate].RemoveAll(eh, eh)
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like this worked but it wasn't until GC ran. Is that what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes... You can tell if it is doing anything by trying just the GC and seeing if it still reduces the memory. this is assuming you're doing an explicit GC.Collect. If not, then of *course* it's entirely by design; no setting objects to nothing, anything, short of an act of God, will cause memory to get freed unless a GC runs. If you haven't read a good article ever about Garbage Collected memory management, do so, it's very clever - and not rocket science, you'll understand it! (if you already know what it is sorry no insult meant)

Comment: Now if this is the fix... See if you can get by without doing a GC.Collect (if you're doing it) But don't worry if you have to leave the GC.Collect in. You just have to know it will block your entire app for 10-500 millisecs. If you're OK with that, you're OK to use GC. I'm only saying this because lots of people get moralistic about explicit calls to GC.Collect. As a certified armchair theologian, I can tell you with absolute certainty, that even 1 billion extra calls to GC.Collect on your part will not cost you even one extra second in purgatory. Maybe 100ms, tops.